# Epoching Data with no Events in mne?

Tags: power-spectral-density, spectrogram

I am new to Python and signal processsing, and I'm trying to create a spectrogram of EEG data taken during a course of general anesthesia. I would like to use MNE's `tfr_multitaper` function in order to compute the power and `power.plot()` to view the spectrogram.

Before I can do this, however, it seems I need to [epoch](http://neuroimage.usc.edu/brainstorm/Tutorials/Epoching) the raw data. My problem is that I have only seen raw data epoched in MNE using events, and when I try to find events using `mne.findevents` on the pre-processed data (e.g. filtered and resampled) it fails to find any. I am wondering if there is a 'split' function in MNE like in brainstorm that allows aritficial epoch production without events.

Answer (score 0):

Although its quite late to answer. But for new people in the field,

mne.findevents would not work on resampled data, as you have modified the data, it will find no events. so find events on the raw signal, and then resample.

For the second question yes, we can mne.make_fixed_length_epochs, without the events data